# Why is the quaternion rotation looking at something else half of the time?

Tags: xcode, 3d, metal, quaternions, metalkit

Please see attached example code for Xcode/Metal and the video of the issue I've run into.

I want a moving object to look at a point, this works half of the time but the other half of the time the object is looking at something else.

I'm using quaternion for the rotation.

So my question is, why is this happening and how can I solve this?

Code examples are very appreciated.

```
    mutating func calculateGizmo()
    {
        time += 0.03

        let position: float3 = [0,
                                0 + cos(time * 0.7) * 4,
                                0 + sin(time * 0.9) * 4]

        gizmo.position = position

        let lookAtMat4x4 = float4x4(eye: position, center: [0, 0, 0], up: [0, 1, 0])

        gizmo.transform.quaternion = simd_quatf(lookAtMat4x4)
    }
```

[Video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7nn9u55qigiaeew/QuaternionFlip2.mov?dl=0)

[Code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hmznglt1k7qqpr0/QuaternionFlip2.zip?dl=0)

I'm trying to to make an object look at a point, and expected it to do so all the time. But it only does that half of the time as it is moving around in 3D space.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be doing the correct thing from what I can see. You're asking the lookat function to ignore the existence of the x axis, so you've constrained it to work within the YZ plane only. The result is then as expected.

In other words, when the position is directly beneath the point (0,0,0), you're asking it to direct the Z axis in the direction of (0,1,0), whilst at the same time asking it to ignore that by focussing the Y axis with an up axis of (0,1,0). So yeah, it's just trying to maintain the constraints you've given it.

By the sounds of it, given that you are trying to constrain the rotation in the YZ plane, it seems like you probably want to maintain an up axis of (1,0,0) or (-1,0,0) ?